# Artifactory: Error during System Import checksum calculation

Tags: artifactory

I'm migrating my Artifactory Server from Win to Linux Docker.
Basically followed the following guide (method 1): https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/important-notes

When i run the system import on the new instance (with the filestore and all it's files already in place) i receive the following errors during checksum calculation for the artefacts:

```
2023-10-13T13:23:28.300Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [a9bc079fe0fde618] [o.j.s.b.BinaryServiceImpl:380 ] [0fde618|art-import-5]
 - Can't calculate missing checksum information for binary with SHA1 '891df3686ff79ce41fee82e506e072e406914742' : Checksum not calculated yet.
2023-10-13T13:23:28.300Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [a9bc079fe0fde618] [.r.d.i.DbRepoImportHandler:378] [0fde618|art-import-5]
 - Import error: from: /tmp_mnt/20231013.135528/repositories/mavencentral-cache/com/atomikos/transactions-jms/maven-metadata.xml to mavencentral-cache:com/atomikos/transactions-jms/maven-metadata.xml 
 reason: Could not import file '/tmp_mnt/20231013.135528/repositories/mavencentral-cache/com/atomikos/transactions-jms/maven-metadata.xml into mavencentral-cache:com/atomikos/transactions-jms/maven-metadata.xml.: /tmp_mnt/20231013.135528/repositories/mavencentral-cache/com/atomikos/transactions-jms/maven-metadata.xml:
 File doesn't exist.
 Either a matching binary is missing or you need to verify your export includes content.
 Otherwise, check the 'Exclude Content' checkbox
```

I validated the file is present in the correct location in the filestore.
Furthermore after system import when i manually redeploy this file e.g. via the UI it calculates the checksum correctly, inserts the binary into the matching db table and uses the file that has been there before.
This seems to be a general issue, as my instance has > 50k artefacts and none is correctly calculated. So basically my binaries table is empty.

How could i debug best what's going on and why it's not working?
Is it possible to somehow start a reindex or is this only done during import?